# How to display timer from managed bean using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, managed-bean

I am currently working on how to pass Date from managed bean to javascript, Then display it as a timer with format `"hh:mm:ss aa"`, I have try but it doesn't work.

Code: `DateTimeManagmentMB.java` (`Managed Bean`)

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Named(value = "dateTimeManagmentMB")
@RequestScoped
public class DateTimeManagmentMB {

private String dateFormated = new String();
private Date date = new Date();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

    dateFormated = df.format(calendar.getTime());
    date = calendar.getTime();
}

public String getdateFormated() {
    return dateFormated;
}

public void setdateFormated(String dateFormated) {
    this.dateFormated = dateFormated;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Code: `time.xhtml`

```
<h:head>
    <script>
        var myVar = setInterval(function() {
            initTimer()
        }, 1000);

        function initTimer(date){
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="initTimer(#{dateTimeManagmentMB.date});">
    <p id="timer"></p>
</h:body>
```

**Note**, What I want to do here is to rely fully on the server to use and display the time and not depends on the client, If there is another approach for this situation tell me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about converting it to a timestamp and creating a javascript date object from it

```
<h:head>
    <script>
        var intervalDuration = 1000;
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var myVar = setInterval(function() {
            updateDisplay()
        }, intervalDuration );

        function updateDisplay() {
            currentTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + intervalDuration);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTime;
        }
        function initTimer(time){
            currentTime = new Date(time);
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body onload="initTimer(#{dateTimeManagmentMB.date.time});">
    <p id="timer"></p>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Yea you would have to format your date in javascript. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript for some ideas around formatting it.

Comment: @Magicano I updated the code, the timing will likely be slightly off but pretty close. There are some ways you could get it much closer but the code should be just fine now.

Comment: @Magicano I dont think a 1 second a request is going to be to taxing on a server however doing it is not necessary  unless you MUST have the exact time.